# Reincarnate a minion with the Ancestral Spirit deathrattle

Tags: hearthstone

What happens when you use [Reincarnate](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7731-reincarnate) ('Destroy a minion, then return it to life with full Health') on a minion that has the [Ancestral Spirit](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/526-ancestral-spirit) deathrattle (Give a minion "Deathrattle: Resummon this minion.)? Does it result in two copies of that minion? Also how does it effect minions like [Harvest Golem](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/386-harvest-golem) that summon a minion on death?

Additionally, what interesting plays can occur using this combo? I assume the combo + [Baron Rivendare](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7740-baron-rivendare) would be hilarious in conjunction with a card as strong as [Cairne Bloodhoof](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/498-cairne-bloodhoof)

Comment: Just for fun: [How to Baron Rivendare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bF8jhFb8c1o). If you don't like montage parodies, stay away.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's take the example you presented with the Harvest Golem.

If you play Ancestral Spirit on him, and then use Reincarnate, he will die, spawning the 2/1 token, then he will respawn twice, once from Ancestral Spirit and once from Reincarnate. So at then end you'll have, one 2/1 token, and two 2/3 Harvest Golem.

Now just for fun, think about the following combo :
play Baron Rivendare
then next turn play Leroy, use Ancestral Spirit twice and Reincarnate !!!
Enjoy !

Comment: can you clarify by "respawn twice"?  Do you end up with 1 or 2 harvest golems.

Comment: i clarified with what you will exactly get on board

Comment: You can have 6 Leroy attack the same turn if you make sure your Baron survives the turn before that. Requires: Baron R. on board, 10 mana and 1x Leroy, 2x Ancestral Spirit and 1xReincarnate

Answer (score 1):

As Shunwoo already explained what happens, I'd like to add a combo: A friend told me about a certain Raptor whose attack becomes double of the attack of an arbitrarily selectable minion on your side. The typical strategy is to have two exemplaries of this Raptor on the field, and to keep alternately sending them back to hand and re-summoning them, thus making them buff up each other. But now imagine instead putting Ancestral Spirit on either of them, and then using Reincarnate!

I think the Raptor in question is different from Unearthed Raptor. But in combination with Unearthed Raptor, Ancestral Spirit + Reincarnate can exhibit quite an amount of power too: Imagine you put Ancestral Spirit on an Unearthed Raptor, then summon another one! There you have two Raptors your enemy can kill both, or never! And with Reincarnate, you can increase this number to three, then to four, then to five... If you have means to get Reincarnate back to your hand multiple times (I think there even is a card returning all cards with the same name), then you can build up an insane army of Unearthed Raptors, that won't die as long as at least one Ancestral Spirit minion survives!

And by the way, Rivendare can truly be insane with these. He's so terrible in each of the combos! For example, if in the first combo you resummon the first Raptor twice, thus having 4 times the attack of the remaining Raptor, plus one with double the attack plus the third one, Rivendare gives you ADDITIONALLY one with 8 times, and one with 16 times! Or for the second combo, as long as you have Rivendare on the field, your Unearthed Raptors will even increase in number! And your growth by Reincarnate will triple in SPC (Summons Per Card)! Additionally, you can put the originating Ancestral Spirit on him - his bulk is really not bad, especially if you get Divine Spirit on him too.

Comment: I think it doesn't work like that, since the raptor doesn't die if you send him back to your hand. So deathrattle effects won't trigger. And Unearthed Raptor will loose the deathrattle effect it got from Ancestral Spirit if you send him back to your hand.

Comment: @Rob I think you somewhat misunderstood the idea. Sending the raptor back to hand is what you usually would do, then replay it to use the other raptor's attack power. Reincarnate, however, takes the place of both sending the card back to hand (kills it instead), and resummoning it. Also, the first two combos are unrelated. And I think they're about different raptors.